# Pyspark - Select , Group and Analyse the log

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

This is my table

```
 User    | eventid | timestamp
 ----------------------------
 root    | 100004 | 2020-07-02 12:01:40
 test    | 100001 | 2020-07-02 12:21:23
 test    | 100002 | 2020-07-02 13:22:56
 test    | 100003 | 2020-07-02 13:27:07
```

Using python, read the event log table, and first group the logs for User, then if grouped logs has 3 eventids (100001,100002 and 100003) and if the events happened in order ( first:100001, second:100002 and third:100003) create a log for this correlation events.

The log is:

```
"Correlation id: Cor101 user: User eventid: 100001,100002,100003 time : 2020-07-02 13:28:00
```

Comment: This is the task, what have you come up with so far?

Comment: I am able to group the user, and see if the 3 event happens, but can not compare the datetime within 3 events